# How to customize headerLeft React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I customize headerLeft TabNavigator of React Navigation.

Here's one of my screens :

[image: headerLeft]

I want to remove the `Back` from the `headerLeft`

Is it possible ?

Here's my code :

```
DetailTabs = TabNavigator({
DetailResult:{
    screen:DetailResult,
    navigationOptions:{
        title:'Detail Penginapan',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontSize:14,
            textAlign: "center",
            flex: 1,
        },
        tabBarVisible: false,
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor:'#4A94FB',
            borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white'
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to set `headerBackTitle` to `null`. Check out the [docs for `headerLeft`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headerleft) for more info.

Like this:

```
DetailTabs = TabNavigator({
DetailResult:{
    screen:DetailResult,
    navigationOptions:{
        title:'Detail Penginapan',
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontSize:14,
            textAlign: "center",
            flex: 1,
        },
        tabBarVisible: false,
        headerStyle:{
            backgroundColor:'#4A94FB',
            borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerBackTitle: null,
    }
}
})
```

Comment: it should be placed on the previous screen

Answer (score 5):

By default, HeaderBackButton component is used. You can implement it and use it to override the back button styles, press props, for example:
link to [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft)

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';

//in newer versions use:
//import {HeaderBackButton} from '@react-navigation/elements';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  custom: {
  // Custom styles here
  }
});

<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <HeaderBackButton
        {...props}
        style={styles.custom}
        onPress={() => {
        // Do something
        }}
      />
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

If you want full control, you can use your custom back button component, example:

```
import { CustomBackButton } from 'path/to/custom/component';

<Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{
    headerLeft: (props) => (
      <CustomBackButton {...props} />
    ),
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: This helps for me, thanks! Also, you can configure your header setting in the screen component. It can help in some cases.
`const SpecificScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: (...props) => (
        <HeaderBackButton
          {...props}
          onPress={handlePressBack}
          label=' '
          tintColor={headerTintColor}
        />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
    return (<Text> Test</Text>)
}`

Answer (score 1):

Key is to put this code from where the back button is clicked, not in App.js
In sample below, for Icon to work, use import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    // what ever
    };

    this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity                
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
        >
         <Icon style = {{paddingLeft : 10}} name="arrow-left" size={26} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        ),
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can customize our headers icon like this by targeting page header.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "hello",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#f4511e",
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerTitleStyle: {
        alignItems: "center",
        fontWeight: "bold",
      },
      headerLeft: () => (
       <Button onPress={handleBackPress}>
         <ArrowLeftCircleIcon className="h-36" size={30} color="black" />
       </Button>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```